# How to display information on rollover image like facebook people taging

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I wonder if anyone can post a code example on how I can display some information when I hover a certain pixel cordinate on an image (just like when I hover a picture on a facebook image and it displays a text of who that person is that I currently have my mouse pointer over).

The diffrence between facebook and my solution is that my picture is not a picture which contains people, but multiple graphs on same picture, so alot of image pixelcordinates is going to display some data when I hover over them.

I also want my sollution to be webbased, and if possible only contain javascript, jquery css html.

Thanks so much in advance =)

Comment: you can try imagemap of html http://www.javascriptkit.com/howto/imagemap.shtml

Comment: like @jimy says, use an image map.

Answer (score 0):

> ike @jimy says, use an image map. – Alex Thomas 6 mins ago

But to answer your question "...wonder if anyone can post a code example..." i've done this:

**HTML**

```
<img name="n00000001" src="http://ajthomas.co.uk/shapes.png" width="300" height="300" border="0" id="n00000001" usemap="#m_00000001" alt="" /><map name="m_00000001" id="m_00000001">

<area shape="rect" coords="28,179,116,256" href="#" title="square" alt="square" />

<area shape="circle" coords="228,66, 45" href="#" title="round" alt="round" />

<area shape="poly" coords="60,32,22,72,51,120,104,109,111,54,60,32" href="#" title="Poly" alt="Poly" />
```

I've put it on jsfiddle for you too - http://jsfiddle.net/ajthomascouk/xsrzz/

I used fireworks, but i'm sure there is free tools out there too.

Hope this helps.

**Update**

> i'm sure there is free tools out there
>   too.

Yup, [Gimp](http://www.gimp.org/) can do it using this [plugin](http://docs.gimp.org/2.6/en/plug-in-imagemap.html)

Good luck...

Comment: if it helped, and your happy with the answer, please accept it :D

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few links for the same.They make use of a css technique known as "image maps"

http://www.frankmanno.com/ideas/css-imagemap/

http://frankmanno.com/ideas/css-imagemap-redux/

http://www.noobcube.com/tutorials/html-css/css-image-maps-a-beginners-guide-/